# There's an issue with Input in my Python code

Tags: python

so I'm a beginner in python and I was trying to get an input function to work. It looks to me like Python isn't taking the data I give it, like it's not reading user input correctly. here is my code:

```
var = input
    input("press ENTER to choose an app")
    if var==1:
        clock() 
    elif var==2:
        oshelp()
    elif var==3:
        ebooks()
    elif var==4:
        what_is_new()
    else:
        print("Application Not Found.")
```

right now, the IDLE just prints "Application Not Found" even when i type a valid number and I'm not sure why. can anyone help me with this? (please include examples). Thanks!

Comment: check your type. Is input a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Comment: Is this your actual code? If so, you need to do `var = input("press ENTER to choose an app")` to store the input value in `var`.

Comment: First of all, your indentation is bad in the question. Assuming it's fine in your own code, `var` has been set equal to the `input`  function, and pressing ENTER  twice doesn't really make sense

Comment: thanks for all the info/help!

Answer (score 2):

Your issue occurs on the first line

`var = input`

You are setting `var` equal to the function `input`, not the returning value.

How you have it, if you were to write `x = var("Enter: ")`, this would do the same as `x = input("Enter: ")`.

You actually need to do `var = input("Enter: ")`, but this will return a value, of type `string`, so when you compare this value to `1`, even if the user enters `1`, it will return false, as they are different data types.

You can either cast the input to an `integer` value, or compare the inputted value to `strings`.

```
var = input("Enter: ")
if var == "1":
```

or

```
var = int(input("Enter: "))
if var == 1
```

I would personally use the top one, as the program wouldn't crash if entered a non-int value.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The python input returns a string and you are comparing ints. If you would like to compare ints, then:

```
inputInt = int(input("please ENTER"))
```

or you could use eval

```
inputInt = eval(input("please ENTER"))
```

be careful with eval as it can cause problems, but it will handle just numbers and floats for you.

Answer (score 0):

The input will be a string and not ints. You can change your conditions from checking `var == 1` to `var == "1"` etc. Or you can create an int from the input, using `int(input())`. However beware of the case where the input is not convertible to an `int` in that case an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

`input` returns a `string`, but you're checking it against `ints`. One way to do this would be to check the input, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response). You could also just compare it to strings:

```
if var == '1':
```

Or convert the input to an `int` directly:

```
var = int(input(...))
```

Be careful with the last one, as it will fail if the user does not input a valid `int`.